# CLASSPATH issue in Hadoop on Cygwin while running "hadoop version" command

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I have installed Hadoop version 2.1 beta from Apache on Windows using Cygwin terminal. Running the command `hadoop version` gets me this error :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo
```

Comment: it got resolved by adding below parameters in "hadoop" script. -classpath "$(cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH")"

Comment: Initially the command in "hadoop" script under ${HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}/bin/hadoop was as - "$JAVA" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
changed it to  exec "$JAVA" -classpath "$(cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH")" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"

Comment: If this fixed your issue, please detail the fix in an answer and then mark it as the accepted solution so that future people will benefit from your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

you can also add the following to your ~/.bashrc

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(cygpath -pw $(hadoop classpath)):$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

this solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue when trying to install Hadoop 2.2.0 on windows 2008 Server Sp1 64bit.

I have installed cygwin64 and configured openssh.

The answer by user2870991 works for me. 
Modify the \hadoop\bin\hadoop script as below, comment the original exec line and insert the new one.

```
  #exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
  #add the -claspath "$(cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH")" TO FIX the script running in cygwin
  exec "$JAVA" -classpath "$(cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH")" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the below statement in hadoop-config.sh @ line no 285

```
CLASSPATH=`cygpath -wp "$CLASSPATH"`

//Comments goes here

if [ "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" != "" ]; then
  # Prefix it if its to be preceded
  if [ "$HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST" != "" ]; then
    CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:${CLASSPATH}
  else
    CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}
  fi
fi
```

Output :

```
admin@admin-PC /cygdrive/e/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/bin
$ ./hadoop version
Hadoop 2.2.0
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1529768
Compiled by hortonmu on 2013-10-07T06:28Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 79e53ce7994d1628b240f09af91e1af4
This command was run using /E:/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
```