# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo

Tags: hadoop, java-home

Hi I have just started learing Hadoop. I am following "Hadoop The definitive guide" book. While setting up Hadoop in Window 7 following "Apendix A" of the book, I am getting error

"`Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo`"

when I am running the command

`hadoop version`

Can anyone have an idea how to correct this or tell me what I am missing?
I am using Cygwin64.
[image]

Comment: Did you try to work with `hdfs` or run some examples like `wordcount`? Maybe it's just a problem with `VersionInfo`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CLASSPATH issue in Hadoop on Cygwin while running "hadoop version" command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363402/classpath-issue-in-hadoop-on-cygwin-while-running-hadoop-version-command)

Answer (score 1):

if you add following line in the end of hadoop-config.sh ( available in HADOOP_INSTALL\libexec), it should work.

CLASSPATH=`'cygpath -wp "$CLASSPATH"'`

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue on oracle linux by adding HADOOP_PREFIX=

Comment: what did you put as the path?

Comment: HADOOP_PREFIX points to the root path of the hadoop installation