# Unable to find Namenode class when setting up Hadoop on Windows 8

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin

Trying to set up Hadoop 2.4.1 on my machine using Cygwin and I'm stuck when I try to run

```
$ hdfs namenode -format
```

which gives me

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
```

I think it's due to an undefined environment variable, since I can run

```
$ hadoop version
```

without a problem. I've defined the following:

JAVA_HOME

HADOOP_HOME

HADOOP_INSTALL

as well as adding the Hadoop \bin and \sbin (and Cygwin's \bin) to the Path. Am I missing an environment variable that I need to define?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like the file hadoop\bin\hdfs also has to be changed like the hadoop\bin\hadoop file described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363402/classpath-issue-in-hadoop-on-cygwin-while-running-hadoop-version-command).

The end of the file must be changed from:

```
exec "$JAVA" -Dproc_$COMMAND $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
```

to

```
exec "$JAVA" -classpath "$(cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH")" -Dproc_$COMMAND $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
```

I assume I'll have to make similar changes to the hadoop\bin\mapred and hadoop\bin\yarn when I get to using those files.