# Hadoop version command not working

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am new to hadoop and trying to configure in Ubuntu.I have followed [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm) tutorial to configure hadoop. 
I have set all environment variable in ~/.bashrc file. I have tested in command prompt using echo command and its show correct path.

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFC_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path = $HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin/:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

**output of env**

```
:/$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/usr/local/hadoop
:/$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
:/$ echo $HADOOP_PREFIX
/usr/local/hadoop
```

But i have run hadoop version command and its shows below error.
 Can someone help me to resolve this error?

```
**/$ hadoop version
Error: Could not find or load main class =**
```

Comment: Seems like a classpath issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363402/classpath-issue-in-hadoop-on-cygwin-while-running-hadoop-version-command

Comment: @tuxdna I tried that solution but no luck.again same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in thus way :

> $> nano /etc/environment or environment

put all path there and after run

> $> source /etc/enviroment

Comment: thanks . but its not working. anything i did wrong? please provide more information

Comment: Did anyone find a solution on this matter? I followed the same step-by-step tutorial and I have stacked at the same point.